# Rellenar ListView con ArrayAdapter en android

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando rellenar un ListView usando mi propia clase ArrayAdapter, obteniendo los datos de un servicio web.

Me da error de

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

En la linea

> alFilms.add(new Films(film.getString("title"),film.getInt("release_year"), film.getInt("length")));

`alFilms` es mi `ArrayList<Films>`

Este es mi código:

```
try {
     //En resultado guardo el Objeto json
     JSONArray arrayFilms=new JSONArray(s);
         for(int i=0; i<arrayFilms.length(); i++){
             JSONObject film= arrayFilms.getJSONObject(i);
             alFilms.add(new Films(film.getString("title"),film.getInt("release_year"), film.getInt("length")));
        }
            adaptador= new FilmsAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_films, alFilms);
            lvFilms.setAdapter(adaptador);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La variable `alFilms` en este punto, tiene como valor `null`.

```
 alFilms.add(new Films(film.getString("title"),film.getInt("release_year"), film.getInt("length")));
```

En todo caso, dado que no has colocado el código por completo, verifica que la variable `alFilms` esté instanciada cuando llegue a invocar al método `add`.

Realizalo de la siguiente forma: inicias la aplicación en modo depuración (debug), colocas un punto de quiebre (breakpoint) en la línea de código en la que agregas un elemento nuevo y verás si `alFilms` se encuentra instanciada.

Comment: Era Eso, no la tenía inicializada, Mucha gracias,